# iOS How to add view to keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit, uikeyboard

Ive seen an app that seems to add a text field to the top of the slide up keyboard such that when the keyboard appears the text field slides up with it and is inside of it. How is that done?

Comment: It's called the `inputAccessoryView` - docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619627-inputaccessoryview

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input accessory view for that as follows.

```
let customView = textfield
textField.inputAccessoryView = customView
```

You should set the position of textfield whenever the keyboard is hidden